# get date from the jquery datepicker in the rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form where the date has to be selected and it has to be passed to an action. But it is not passing as params to that action. I am using jquery datepicker for selecting dates.

View page

```
<%=f.text_field :due_date%>
```

Controller page

```
def create
      @task = Task.new(params[:task])
       if @task.valid?
          @task.due_date=params[:task][:due_date]
          @task.save
          redirect_to(calenders_path(:date=>@task.due_date,:task_name=>params[:task][:task_name]))
      else
         render :action=>"new"
      end
end
```

Here only :task_name is passing as params
Please help

Comment: Please put the view code in there, and format it correctly! Also, do you have `attr_accessible :due_date` in the  Task model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def create
      @task = Task.new(params[:task])
       if @task.save
          redirect_to(calenders_path(:date=>@task.due_date,:task_name=>@task.task_name))
       else
          render :action=>"new"
      end
end
```

The `due_date` param should already be populated by the first line. You might be setting it to null with `@task.due_date=params[:task][:due_date]`.